# Is it possible to have a Game Center "LowestScore" Leaderboard?

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

I've read that Game Center Leaderboard scores are [only updated when the newly posted score is greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697478/update-a-score-already-submitted-to-game-center) than the already existing score.

This made me wonder if it is possible at all to have a Game Center Leaderboard that stores scores counting down, for example "time to complete level". Can this still be achieved with the correct setup of the Leaderboard, for example with sorting and formatting modifiers?

And just to confirm, is it really not possible to have a Game Center Leaderboard simply accept the value that you send to it, regardless of whether it is greater or smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose low to high or high to low leaderbord type in iTunes Connect.

And you can always send any value to Game Center server, it's just that it will not save it unless it's higher* than the current score.

* if it's a low to high leaderboard, the value that is lower is actually counted as a higher score.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! Too bad you can't just overwrite scores to store arbitrary values.

Comment: Do you have a source that states that it won't save unless it's higher?

Comment: It is mentioned in some WWDC videos but I really have no time to watch all of them and tell you exact timestamp. I can confirm it based on my experience with games like [this one](http://itunes.apple.com/hr/app/space-trikoders/id484006499?mt=8).

Comment: If you ever played a game on an iPhone or iPad you'll know that this is the way the leaderboards in Game Center work... ;-)