# iOS game center How to decrease score?

Tags: ios, game-center

A user's score decreases, then commit the new lower score to game center, but Apple will retain the higher score submitted before.

How to change game center's score, let it update to the lower score?

### UPDATE:

It is top list, the higher score the better. The scores are changing everyday. A user can use his score for doing something, then his score decreases. If he wins, his score increases.

First day:
[image]

Second day:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a Game Center "LowestScore" Leaderboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780649/is-it-possible-to-have-a-game-center-lowestscore-leaderboard)

Comment: @esqew No. It is top list, the higher score the better. But the scores are changing all the time. A user has his score, he can use his score for doing something, then his score decreases. If he won, his score increase.

Comment: you can't decrease the score.

Comment: i don't really get your english, but this might help: in iTunes Connect there is leaderboard option called **Score Submission Type** you can change it **Most Recent Score**

Comment: @holex But I've seen an app can decrease score. https://itunes.apple.com/app/brazil-world-football-2014/id855034878   Is it possible to reset score, then commit again?

Comment: @Gank, the leaderboard always shows the _top_ score in that app (and that app clearly says that); how did you get that idea about it decreases the points in the _GameCenter_?

Comment: @holex A betting app, users can use the scores to bet, if he bet right, his score increases, otherwise he costs his score. https://itunes.apple.com/app/free-points-betting-game/id876355499

Comment: @Gank, inside the app, _yes_ – on the leaderboard, _no_.

Comment: @holex But I really see that app can do it. https://itunes.apple.com/app/brazil-world-football-2014/id855034878  I saw it just now. Maybe I was wrong. It now doesn't work. Thanks for your  help.

Comment: @Gank, what are you seeing exactly? and where do you see that? inside the app? or in the GameCenter? you could be more specific rather than repeating the same thing over and over...

Comment: @holex I saw my score was 1750 yesterday and today is 500. But just now, it became back to 1750. Maybe I am wrong, you're right. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can increase and decrease a user score over time on the same leaderboard, the option is called **Most Recent Score**

- in iTunes Connect select your app
- then click **Manage Game Center**
- you can add a new leaderboard or edit a not submitted leaderboard
- and change the **Score Submission Type** to **Most Recent Score**

Comment: Great answer. I usually set that "Score Submission Type" to "Best Score", and was not aware of the option "Most Recent Score".